# gnuplot, output figure size

Tags: plot, size, gnuplot

I have tried to set output figure size by a term size with png or ps. Neither works. I got random emoticons and signs in the terminal (gnuplot v. 5.2).

my script which I executed in wxt terminal by `load scriptname`:

```
reset
set term png size 800,400
set ylabel "name1" 
set xlabel  font ",16"
set ylabel  font ",16"
set xtics font ",16"
set ytics font ",16"
set title "title" offset 0,-3.5
set title font ",16"
set key font ",14"
set xlabel "name 2" 
set ytics (11, 12, 13, 14)
set xtics 0.5
#set nokey
set key left
```

Without `set term png size 800,400` line (values are for purpose of example), it executes the plot perfectly, if I expand the plot via mouse it works as well but I would like to produce many plots with the same size but *bigger* than the default. Expanding by mouse every time did not make the same size plot.

Comment: What do you want? A graph in a wxt terminal which you can save from there as a PNG or directly save a PNG file without displaying your graph in the interactive wxt terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways to get a PNG file:

1. display your graph in a wxt terminal (and optimize it until you like it). And then save it as file (in my case I have the options PNG, PDF, SVG or EMF).
2. set a PNG terminal and set the output file name. The output will be directly written to the file and not shown in the wxt terminal terminal.

**Output in wxt terminal and manually save as PNG**

```
reset session
set term wxt size 1000,500   # or any other size you want
plot sin(x)
```

[image]

**Direct output to PNG**

```
reset session
set term pngcairo size 1000,500   # or any other size you want
set output "myOutput.png"
plot sin(x)
set output
```